# NSAttributedString text position

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsattributedstring

I sub-classed a `UILabel`, so I can use this `TitleLabel` on several places. This `TitleLabel` has a custom font. The `lineheight` is set with an `NSAttributedString`.

**This is the `drawTextInRect` override method:**

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.text = @"THIS IS A TEST";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 15.f;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 15.f;

    [attStr addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,7)];
    [attStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length)];
    [attStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:TITLE_FONT_NAME size:TITLE_FONT_SIZE] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length)];

    self.attributedText = attStr;

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

The background colors are added for test purposes. As you can see, the yellow background color has the right position. The text **THIS IS** should be in the yellow background, but is positioned above the background.
`TITLE_FONT_SIZE` is `15`, defined somewhere else.

[image]

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Have the same issue.
Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the font size, so that if the font is too big the text gets cut. That's normal, change your font size according to the rect size. Make it be something like this:

```
[attStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:TITLE_FONT_NAME size: MIN(rect.size.height*0.4,rect.size.width*0.4)] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length)];
```

**EDIT**

Not sure which rectangle gets passed to the method. There's nothing in the doc, maybe is the frame and not the view bounds. Try this:

```
[super drawTextInRect: [self convertRect: rect fromView: nil] ];
```

Comment: The text is not cut off, it's moved. When I remove the addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName line, The text is in the yellow square. The size is fine then, but the font family isn't. 
Your code doesn't work either, the text still get's moved.
Isn't there a way to only set the fontWithName, without setting the font size?

Comment: Ok maybe I got it. Try what I've written above, though I am not sure of this.

Comment: Btw the cut text is a direct consequence of the text being moved.